# google app engine is detecting python25 as default

Tags: python, google-app-engine

hi i am trying to install `Google app engine` with `windows MSI` i have two python version on my windows one is `python25` and other is `python26`, and i have python26 path set in my `environmental variables`, but Google app engine is detecting python25 as `default prerequisite`, what should i do which makes Google app engine to detect python26.

or if i let it to use python25 then can i change that later? and how?

---

[image]

Comment: App Engine only supports 2.5 right now. 2.7 is in the works but there's a trusted tester program you can sign up for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present, Google App Engine's production servers only run Python 2.5.2. You should be using Python 2.5 on the development server as well, as having a different environment for testing and production leads to scenarios where, for example, you use syntax that's valid in 2.6 which passes your tests fine, and the unexpectedly gives you frustrating errors when deployed to production.

It should be noted that the Python 2.7 runtime on the production servers is currently in the Trusted Testers stage, and should be available for use in the next few months, but until it is, it's best to stay with 2.5 for development.

Comment: You'll be fine with 2.6 as long as you don't use features of packages that were added in 2.6 (i.e., pay attention to the "new in 2.6" that you might see in package documentation).